# Are there any traditional tunes for Yishaya 26:20

Tags: song-poetry, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

During the Corona virus pandemic a verse which comes to mind is Yishaya 26:20:

> לֵךְ עַמִּי בֹּא בַחֲדָרֶיךָ, וּסְגֹר דלתיך בַּעֲדֶךָ; חֲבִי כִמְעַט-רֶגַע, עַד יעבור זָעַם.
>
> Go, my people, enter your rooms and shut the doors behind you; hide yourselves for just a while until the wrath passes.

Does someone know any uplifting tunes to which this has been sung?

Comment: Do you have any personal favorite tunes? Oftentimes people reuse their favorite tunes on new lyrics to create the right sentiments. Anyhow, based on that, this is not on topic.

Comment: Yes, it's called the trop

Comment: (Not that this makes the question any more on-topic, but see BK 60b which applies this verse to a pandemic.)

Answer (score 4):

It’s not exactly traditional (only a few years old), but you might appreciate [this tune](https://youtu.be/Phks4BWbKH4) sung by Yaakov Shwekey.